# Using Hadoop InputFormat in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working on a file parser for Spark that can basically read in **n** lines at a time and place all of those lines as a single row in a dataframe.
I know I need to use `InputFormat` to try and specify that, but I cannot find a good guide to this in Python.
Is there a method for specifying a custom `InputFormat` in Python or do I need to create it as a scala file and then specify the jar in `spark-submit`?

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use the InputFormats with Pyspark.

Quoting from the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html),

> PySpark can also read any Hadoop InputFormat or write any Hadoop
>   OutputFormat, for both ‘new’ and ‘old’ Hadoop MapReduce APIs.

Pass the `HadoopInputFormat` class to any of these methods of `pyspark.SparkContext` as suited,

- [hadoopFile()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.hadoopFile)
- [hadoopRDD()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.hadoopRDD)
- [newAPIHadoopFile()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.newAPIHadoopFile)
- [newAPIHadoopRDD()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD)

To read **n** lines, `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.NLineInputFormat` can be used as the HadoopInputFormat class with the newAPI methods.

Comment: The `hadoopFile` methods are what should be used to read the file, the RDD methods don't provide an input URI parameter.

Comment: I actually don't know how to use the RDD methods... I was reading the source code, and both methods return RDD's...

Comment: yes, these RDD methods assume the file is already read by a sc, using methods like `addFile()` which accepts URI. I added those methods with that in context.

Comment: Well it's not throwing errors but it's also not reading multiple lines like I want it to... guess it's time to post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot find a good guide to this in Python

In the Spark docs, under "Saving and Loading Other Hadoop Input/Output Formats", there is an Elasticsearch example + links to an HBase example.

> can basically read in n lines at a time... I know I need to use InputFormat to try and specify that

There is [`NLineInputFormat`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/NLineInputFormat.html) specifically for that.

---

This is a rough translation of some Scala code I have from [NLineInputFormat not working in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320325/nlineinputformat-not-working-in-spark)

```
def nline(n, path):
  sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate
  conf = {
    "mapreduce.input.lineinputformat.linespermap": n
  }

  hadoopIO = "org.apache.hadoop.io"
  return sc.newAPIHadoopFile(path, 
    "org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.NLineInputFormat", 
    hadoopIO + ".LongWritable", 
    hadoopIO + ".Text", 
    conf=conf).map(lambda x : x[1])  # To strip out the file-offset

n = 3
rdd = nline(n, "/file/input")
```

> and place all of those lines as a single row in a dataframe

With `NLineInputFormat`, each string in the RDD is actually new-line delimited. You can `rdd.map(lambda record : "\t".join(record.split('\n')))`, for example to put make one line out them.